# How to change colour to parentheses/brackets?

Tags: themes, rstudio

Hellou everybody
I wanted to make myself custom theme for RStudio using tmtheme-editor, but I run into problem: when I loaded theme in RStudio, it looked differently than shown in editor. I have problems with changing bracket colour. I use "meta.brace" scope, but in RStudio, the colour of brackets seems to matched to "keyword" scope. I have no idea how to fix it.

I tried to play with "keyword" scope and when I change it for example to "source.js keyword" it is fine in editor but not in actual RStudio - keyword related symbols were all white and brackets also.

```
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Meta Brace</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.brace</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FF0084</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I would like to make brackets pink-ish to be mroe visible and keyword symbols/characters/text blue-ish. I though using editor will be easier than going through many themes to find right one but I totally didnt expect this.
Thanks.